# range query not working as intended [elasticsearch]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am executing a simple range query. But I see that an empty result being returned. But I know that they are many records/documents that satisfy the query.

Below are the 3 types of queries I have tried.
(the third one is intended query)

1)

```
"query": {
    "range" : {
        "endTime" : {
            "gte" : 1559076400.0
            }
        }
}
```

2)

```
"query": {
   "bool": {
         "must": [
         {"range" : {
             "endTime" : {
                 "gte" : 1559076401.0
                 }
             }
         }
         ]
        }
      }
```

3)

```
   "query": {
       "bool": {
             "filter": [
            {"range" : {
                "startTime" : {
                    "gt" : 1356873300.0
                    }
                }
            },
            {"range" : {
                "endTime" : {
                    "gte" : 1559076401.0
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
          }
```

All 3 queries return an empty response.

Hope you people can help. Thank you.

Comment: Please add the mapping of index.

Comment: {'mappings': {'addInfo': {'properties': {'addressMap': {'properties': {'*': {'type': 'keyword'}, 'NY:NYC': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'CA:SFO': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}}}, **'endTime': {'type': 'long'}**, 'path': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, 'addId': {'type': 'text', 'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}, **'startTime': {'type': 'long'}**}}}}}

Answer (score 0):

In elastic index, before inserting data, you you need define the fields mappings as date or numbers so that range searches can be applied.
Or keep dynamic mappings ON so that elastic can identify the field types automatically based on inserted data. 
In case of latter, do check the auto generated mappings on your index. 
Also check the date/timestamp format.

Steps to check mappings
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Comment: I checked the mappings, 
'endTime': {'type': 'long'}. This should be compatible with the above query right?
I am new to elastic search. Apologies if the questions are basic.

Comment: Can you remove .0 from query and try?

Comment: same result with or without the decimals.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? Try with “from” and “to” keywords instead of lte gte

Comment: "query": {
    "range" : {
        "endTime" : {
            "from" : 1559076400
            }
        }
     }

results in the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `epoch` time, you need to mention that in the mapping. This is what I did. Basically the `mapping` and the way you stored the data mattered here. I am not sure if we can save any format as we want and query using any format we want. I will do some more research and update the answer if that can be done

1) created the mapping -- to show how the `endTime` mapping is done
2) inserting a few sample documents
3) queried the document using epoch time -- the way you wanted

**Mapping**

```
PUT so_test24
{

    "mappings" : {
      "_doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "endTime" : {

              "type" : "date",
             "format": "epoch_millis"

          }
        }
      }

  }
}
```

**Inserting the documents**

```
 POST /so_test24/_doc
{
    "id": 1,
    "endTime": "1546300800"
}

POST /so_test24/_doc
{
    "id": 2,
    "endTime": "1514764800"
}

POST /so_test24/_doc
{
    "id": 3,
    "endTime": "1527811200"
}

POST /so_test24/_doc
{
    "id": 4,
    "endTime": "1535760000"
}
```

**The search Query**

```
GET /so_test24/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "endTime": {"gte": "1532883892"}
    }
  }
}
```

**The result**

```
    {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "so_test24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "uFIq42sB4TH56W1h-jGu",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "endTime" : "1546300800"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "so_test24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "u1Iq42sB4TH56W1h-zEK",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 4,
          "endTime" : "1535760000"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it mean that I need to provide explicit mapping every time there is a non-string type? [As the current type is long]

Comment: Looks like there was no problem with the mapping. There was some other logical error which lead to the failure.
Thanks for the help.